# Find Website Name from a web application

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have two web site sites on IIS 7 (Default, Custom). Both Sites host the same web  application.

Some of the web application behavior changes depending under what web site it is running. Is there a way for the web application to find out what is the name of the WebSite under which it is handling the current request.

Thank you
Imran

Answer (score 7):

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName
```

will get you the site name as it appears in IIS

```
Request.Url.Authority
```

will get yo the requesting url